# Matplotlib Animation Polygons

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, I am trying to use the animate function with a polygon, to rotate it in the plane.

The code pasted below only draws the first polygon but the animation doesn't work.

Can someone spot what's wrong in the `animate` function?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-30, 30), ylim=(-30, 30))


pts = [[0.,0.], [2.,0.], [9.6,7.6], [9.6,9.6]]


patch = plt.Polygon(pts,closed=None, fill=None, edgecolor='r')
def init():
    patch.pts = [[0.,0.], [2.,0.], [9.6,7.6], [9.6,9.6]]
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(i):

    x1=0.+ 10. * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    x2=2.+ 10. * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    x3=9.6+ 10. * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    x4=9.6+ 10. * np.sin(np.radians(i))

    y1=0.+ 10. * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    y2=0.+ 10. * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    y3=7.6+ 10. * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    y4=9.6+ 10. * np.cos(np.radians(i))


    patch.pts = [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]]


    return patch,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=36,interval=1000,blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
patch.pts = [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]]
```

does not update the vertices of the polygon. You can use set_xy to change the vertices:

```
patch.set_xy([[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]])
```

This will make the plot change on each iteration. The [Matplotlib artists documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html) has more information.

It still doesn't look like the shape is rotating. That's something to do with the coordinates you're using.